# Mac Mail: Replying from "Redirected-to" address

Tags: mail.app, email

I'm phasing out a couple email accounts on one domain (call it "olddomain.com"), and replacing them with news ones on a different domain (call it "newdomain.com"). To make the transition easier, I'm using rules to take email sent to the old accounts and redirect it to the new accounts.

Setting up a redirect rule was easy, but I'm left with a problem: when I reply to a redirected email, the From field is set to the old email address (example@olddomain.com). I can, of course, change the From value to the new email account, but this is too easy to forget. It would be much better if the From field were automatically set to example@newdomain.com.

Is it possible to have replies to redirected mail come from the Resent-To address by default in Mail?